# Horizontal - Vertical connectors in a tree (in place of slanted lines)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, node-connections

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners = 2pt, minimum width = 2cm, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  block/.style = {treenode, rectangle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black},
  phantom/.style = {}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 3in/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}] 
  \node [block] {P1}
    child {node [block] {P2}
      child {node [block] {P3}
        child {node [block] {P4}}
        child {node [block] {P5}}
      }
    }
    child {node [block] {P6}
      child {node [phantom] {}
        child {node [block] {P7}}
      }
    }
    child {node [block] {P8}
      child {node [block] {P9}
        child {node [block] {P10}}
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The connectors between different nodes are slanted lines. How do I get horizontal - vertical lines in place of these?

Comment: Is this useful? http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option is to use `forest`. In this case, you can dispense with the `phantom` node and just use `tier` to align `P7` with the `P4`, `P5` etc. I've also updated your code to use the current syntax for arrows, provided by the `arrows.meta` library as this is now recommended. I like `forest` because specifying a tree involves much less typing!

## Updated Solution (Forest version 2+)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners = 2pt, minimum width = 2cm, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  block/.style = {treenode, rectangle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black},
}

% Forest version 2.1
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    block,
    edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}}
  },
  forked edges
  [P1
    [P2
      [P3
        [P4, tier=terminal]
        [P5]
      ]
    ]
    [P6, calign with current
      [P7, tier=terminal]
    ]
    [P8
      [P9
        [P10]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  ;
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

## Original Solution (Forest version 1)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners = 2pt, minimum width = 2cm, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  block/.style = {treenode, rectangle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black},
}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    block,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [-{Stealth[]}, \forestoption{edge}, thick]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  }
  [P1
    [P2
      [P3
        [P4, tier=terminal]
        [P5]
      ]
    ]
    [P6, calign with current
      [P7, tier=terminal]
    ]
    [P8
      [P9
        [P10]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  ;
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

## Result

The output is the same, basically, regardless of which solution you use.

[image: forest tree]

Comment: Good to see that you also like `forest` :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina ?? You'd not noticed this before?!

Comment: Yes, of course I noticed. I just wanted to make it explicit and to acknowledge your involvement in the `forest` crusade!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you. Though I wouldn't have figured out how to use it at all if you hadn't answered my question about the syntax ;).

Comment: Another advantage of your method is that you can put `\noexpand\pgfonlayer{background}` and `\noexpand\endpgfonlayer` in `edge path=` and then use `(!u.center) -| (.child anchor)` that I was not able to do with `edge from parent path` !

Comment: @Kpym Why do that, though? I guess it depends how you want the final result to look... But that's an interesting use of layering - I'll bear that in mind: thanks ;).

Comment: Yes, it depends what you want. But I wanted this in the beginning, and I was not able to do it. I'm just saying that with `forest` you can do more things ;)

Comment: @Kpym Absolutely! `forest` is pretty amazing. (Although it is misnamed since pretty much the one thing it cannot do - or cannot do at all easily - is accommodate more than one tree!)

Comment: Good to hear all this praise, guys! ;-)  And soon ... a new version coming up! Updating the docs now ... hope you'll volunteer to beta-test a bit!

Comment: About the name: the first version of forest (then called xyforest, since it used xypic) was developed for dealing with multiple (albeit small) trees, all nicely lined up ---I needed it for drawing phonological (autosegmental) representations. And anyways, all the good Xtree names were already taken! ;-)

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I like the name. I just think it a little ironic! Good to know the history of the name, and even better to hear a new version is on its way. The thing I find most difficult about using it, by the way, is the documentation. It is sometimes rather too concise. However, it gets easier if you get somebody to help you over the initial hurdles. [I think a couple of cross-references to the TiKZ manual would have helped me a lot - some of the things which puzzled me were really TiKZ syntax but I didn't know that.]

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Will be happy to help beta-test the new version if I can be of any use.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I would also be happy to beta-test the new version (by the way, good to  hear about a new version!). Please ping me here (if that's OK with **cfr**) for any message.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Fine by me if you'd like to do that since I'll get auto-pinged in that case, as well.

Answer (score 3):

When you say horizontal/vertical, do you mean this?

[image: output]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners = 2pt, minimum width = 2cm, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  block/.style = {treenode, rectangle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black},
  phantom/.style = {},
  edge from parent/.style={draw,red,thick},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)-- ++(0,-3mm) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 3in/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}]
  \node [block] {P1}
    child {node [block] {P2}
      child {node [block] {P3}
        child {node [block] {P4}}
        child {node [block] {P5}}
      }
    }
    child {node [block] {P6}
      child {node [phantom] {}
        child {node [block] {P7}}
      }
    }
    child {node [block] {P8}
      child {node [block] {P9}
        child {node [block] {P10}}
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** I just discovered that we can use `[edge from parent fork down]` style from `trees` library to produce the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xfp}

\psset{
  linecolor = red,
  arrows = ->
}

\def\Label(#1,#2)#3{%
  \psframe[
    framearc = 0.3,
    linecolor = black,
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = black
  ](\fpeval{#1-0.5*\widthBox},\fpeval{#2-0.5*\heightBox})%
   (\fpeval{#1+0.5*\widthBox},\fpeval{#2+0.5*\heightBox})
  \rput(#1,#2){\textcolor{white}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

% parameters
\def\widthBox{1.4}
\def\heightBox{0.4}
\def\horiDist{4.5}
\def\vertDist{1.6}

% drawing
\begin{pspicture}(\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.75*\widthBox},\fpeval{4*\heightBox+3*\vertDist})
  % left
  \Label(\fpeval{1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{2.5*\heightBox+2*\vertDist}){P2}
  \psline(\fpeval{1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{2*\heightBox+2*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{2*\heightBox+\vertDist})
  \Label(\fpeval{1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{1.5*\heightBox+\vertDist}){P3}
  \psline(\fpeval{1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{\heightBox+\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{\heightBox+0.5*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{0.5*\widthBox},\fpeval{\heightBox+0.5*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{0.5*\widthBox},\heightBox)
  \psline(\fpeval{1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{\heightBox+0.5*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{2*\widthBox},\fpeval{\heightBox+0.5*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{2*\widthBox},\heightBox)
  \Label(\fpeval{0.5*\widthBox},\fpeval{0.5*\heightBox}){P4}
  \Label(\fpeval{2*\widthBox},\fpeval{0.5*\heightBox}){P5}
  % middle
  \Label(\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{3.5*\heightBox+3*\vertDist}){P1}
  \psline(\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{3*\heightBox+3*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{3*\heightBox+2*\vertDist})
  \Label(\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{2.5*\heightBox+2*\vertDist}){P6}
  \psline(\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{2*\heightBox+2*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\heightBox)
  \Label(\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{0.5*\heightBox}){P7}
  \psline(\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{1.5*\heightBox+\vertDist-0.1})%
         (\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\heightBox)
  % right
  \Label(\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{2.5*\heightBox+2*\vertDist}){P8}
  \psline(\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{2*\heightBox+2*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{2*\heightBox+\vertDist})
  \Label(\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{1.5*\heightBox+\vertDist}){P9}
  \psline(\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{\heightBox+\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\heightBox)
  \Label(\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{0.5*\heightBox}){P10}
  % connection
  \psline(\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{3*\heightBox+2.5*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{3*\heightBox+2.5*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{3*\heightBox+2*\vertDist})
  \psline(\fpeval{\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{3*\heightBox+2.5*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{3*\heightBox+2.5*\vertDist})%
         (\fpeval{2*\horiDist+1.25*\widthBox},\fpeval{3*\heightBox+2*\vertDist})
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

With this code, all you have to do is choose the width (`\widthBox`) and the height (`\heightBox`) of the boxes, and the horizontal (`\horiDist`) and the vertical (`\vertDist`) distances between them. The drawing will then automatically be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @AlanMunn Ohh! Sorry. I'll remember that.