# How to make an HTA looking thing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, paths

I am try achieve something along the lines of this:

[image: HTA example]

I cannot however figure out how to make these arrows. I have some code that gives me something that is almost right but it is messed up in some places and it fails to automatically pick the path I want (overlapping nodes or such)

```
\path [draw, -latex'] (START) |- (DUMMY) |- (DUMMY2) |- (GOAL);
```

I made two dummy nodes in my attempt to get this thing to follow a path I wanted, which would be DOWN, LEFT, DOWN, as for the "Warm up furnace" -> "Prepare plant and services" step in the picture above.

Can somebody give me a little aid on how to direct these paths better and if possible, without the clutter of extra nodes? I am currently stuck on this and have no idea what to do. Have googled a lot but only get partial answers (like the one above).

Comment: You can check this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218411/9335

Comment: @Kpym Thanks, I will have a look at this one and get back whether it works it not.

Comment: Please: (very nearly) all questions should include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). *Especially* questions about how to draw graphics.

Answer (score 7):

Next time, please provide a Minimum Working Example so that people don't have to copy every word from an image but can cut-and-paste at least the basic structure of the document and textual content of the diagram.

This solution uses `forest` and constructs and adds the labels at the beginning of the nodes automatically. For this, I got very fast, accurate help from [Sašo Živanović's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218995/) to my [question about avoiding multiple labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218988/how-can-i-label-forest-nodes-automatically-adding-labels-as-prefixes-to-nodes).

[image: furnace forest]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp,fixltx2e}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows}
\begin{document}

\forestset{
  tree node/.style = {inner sep=2pt, rounded corners = 2pt, font=\sffamily, rectangle, draw, thick, fill=white, align=center, drop shadow},
  placing node/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw=none, skipping path},
  skipping path/.style={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}, thick]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- (.south)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  },
  /tikz/plan label/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep+=5pt,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [-{Stealth[]}, \forestoption{edge}, thick]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  },
  set root label/.style={
    content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={##1. ##2}{n()}{content()},
    tree node
  },
  set node label/.style={
    content/.wrap 3 pgfmath args={##1.##2 ##3}{n("!r")}{n()}{content()},
    tree node
  },
  set node super label/.style={
    content/.wrap 4 pgfmath args={##1.##2.##3 ##4}{n("!r")}{n("!uu")}{n()}{content()},
    tree node
  },
  before typesetting nodes={% where contains implicit for tree loop: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218995/: Sašo Živanović
    for tree={
      if level=0{
        set root label,
%       content={O. #1},
      }{
        if level=1{
          set node label,
        }{
          if level=3{
            set node super label,
          }{
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
  [Warm\\up furnace
    [Prepare\\plant and\\services
    [, placing node, label={[plan label]right:Plan 0.1: Do in any order}
        [Ensure\\plant is\\ready, calign with current
          [,phantom, tier=bottom]
        ]
        [Ensure\\gas-oil is\\available
        ]
        [Ensure O\textsubscript{2}\\analysis system\\is working
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [\\Start air\\blower, edge label={node [plan label, anchor=south east, above left, midway] {Plan 0: Do in order};}
    ]
    [\\Start oil\\pump
    ]
    [Head\\oil to\\800\textcelsius
      [, placing node, tier=bottom, label={[plan label]left:Plan 0.4: Raise temperature to 800\textcelsius{} while monitoring O\textsubscript{2} and $\triangle$T}
        [Increase\\temperature controller\\as per chart
        ]
        [\\Monitor\\O\textsubscript{2}
        ]
        [\\Monitor\\temperature
        ]
        [Switch\\furnace to\\automatic, calign with current
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  ;
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `pstricks` solution with a `psmatrix` environment and a relatively short code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pdf, x11names]{pstricks}%
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-blur}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-family, mode=text}

\usepackage{twoopt}
\newcommandtwoopt\mybox[3][1.6cm][2.5cm]{\psframebox[shadow=true, blur=true, framearc=0.05]{\parbox[t][#1][c]{#2}{\centering#3}}}

 \begin{document}
 \psset{nodesep=0pt, arrows=->, angleA=-90,angleB=90, armA = 1.5cm, armB=0.5cm, colsep=0.5cm, rowsep=2cm, linearc=0.05}%

 \sffamily
\begin{psmatrix}
%%% nodes
 & \mybox[1.2cm]{0. Warm up \\ furnace}\psspan{2}\\
\mybox{0.1 Prepare \\ plant and \\ services} & \mybox{0.2 Start \\ air blower} & \mybox{0.3 Start \\ oil pump} & \mybox{0.4 Heat \\ oil to \\ \SI{800}{\celsius}} \\
\mybox{0.1.1 Ensure \\ plant is \\ ready} & \mybox{0.1.2 Ensure \\ gas-oil is \\ avalaible} & \mybox[1.6cm][3.2cm]{0.1.3 Ensure O\textsuperscript2 \\ analysis system \\ is working}\\
\mybox[1.6cm][4cm]{0.4.1 Increase \\ temperature controller \\ as per chart} & \mybox{0.4.2 \\ Monitor \\ O\textsuperscript2} & \mybox{0.4.3 \\ Monitor \\ temperature} & \mybox{0.4.4 Switch \\ furnace to \\ automatic}
%%% arrows
\ncangle{1,2}{2,1}\nbput[npos=1.72]{Plan 0: Do in order}\ncangle{1,2}{2,2}\ncangle{1,2}{2,3}\ncangle{1,2}{2,4}
\ncangle{2,1}{3,1}\ncangle{2,1}{3,2}\ncangle{2,1}{3,3}\naput[npos=1.32]{Plan 0.1: Do in any order}
\psset{armA=5.4cm}
\ncangle{2,4}{4,1}\nbput[npos=0.92 ]{Plan 0.4: Raise temperature to \SI{800}{\celsius} while monitoring O\textsuperscript{2} and $\Delta$T}\ncangle{2,4}{4,2}\ncangle{2,4}{4,3}\ncangle{2,4}{4,4}
\end{psmatrix}

    \end{document}
```

[image]