# How can I label forest nodes automatically, adding labels as prefixes to nodes' content exactly once?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles, automation, forest

I was trying to figure out how you might get `forest` to label the nodes in a diagram such as the one featured in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218872/how-to-make-an-hta-looking-thing) automatically. So, the idea is that:

- level 0: content of node should be prefixed with `O.` i.e. if the content specified is `P0`, then the node should be typeset with the content `O. P0`;
- level 1: content should be prefixed with `O.n` where `n` is the number of the child e.g. if the nodes at the first level are specified as `P1` and `P3`, then they should be typeset as `O.1 P1` and `O.2 P3`;
- level 2: content should be prefixed with `O.n.m` where `n` is the child number of the parent and `m` is the child number of the node e.g. if `P1` has a child `P2` then the latter should appear as `O.1.1 P2` and if `P3` has a child `P4` then the latter should be typeset as `O.2.1 P4`.

Level 0 is no problem. I can do that using `content={O. #1}`. I can also get the relevant labels constructed and included in the nodes for levels 1 and 2. However, what I cannot figure out is how to get this added to the content of each node exactly once. Whatever I do, I either end up without the prefix or with a garbled or empty prefix or with multiple copies of the correct prefix.

This is the closest I've got, I think:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\forestset{
  tree node/.style = {align=center, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners = 2pt, text centered, font=\sffamily, rectangle, draw=black},
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    tree node,
    l sep+=5pt,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [-{Stealth[]}, \forestoption{edge}, thick]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  },
  set node label/.style={
    content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={O.##1 ##2}{n()}{content()},
  },
  set node super label/.style={
    content/.wrap 3 pgfmath args={O.##1.##2 ##3}{n("!u")}{n()}{content()},
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      where level=0{
        content={O. #1},
      }{
        where level=1{
          set node label,
        }{
          where level=2{
            set node super label,
          }{
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
  [P0
    [P1
      [P2
      ]
    ]
    [P3
      [P4
      ]
    ]
  ]
  ;
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

This constructs the prefixes correctly but it adds them too often to the nodes!

[image: too many labels!]

I've also tried storing the original content in a macro and then using that in the specification of `content`. However, in that case, I just lose the original contents altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all the `where`s by `if`s.

`where` is defined as `where/.style n args={3}{for tree={if={#1}{#2}{#3}}}`, so it implicitely contains a `for tree` loop.

Comment: Bugger. Thank you very much! [First comment was not directed at you - only the second!] ;) Much appreciated.

Comment: [Here's](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219013/) the example which prompted this question, in case you are interested. (No particular reason you should be, of course.)