# How can I auto label nodes in a forest?

Tags: diagrams, labels, forest

I have tried searching for a solution everywhere however I either haven't been able to see it or it is not there.

I have a forest, I would like to add a label to each node such that 'Deadbeef' would be labelled 1, 'Something' would be labeled 1.1, 'else' 1.2 and then their children 1.1.1 etc.

I know I can do this with the `\label` command, however I am lazy and my tree grows so I don't want to keep numbering trivially.

```
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    grow'=0,
    align=center, 
    base=bottom
},
[Deadbeef
    [Something
        [Generic\\node]
        [Other\\ generic node]
        [That one\\there]        
    ]
    [Else
        [Client\\Side
            [Become\\data]
            [Bathe in\\data]
        ]
        [Server\\Side
            [One with\\data]
            [Meta\\data
                [Update\\main service]
                [Update\\database]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [Kindof
        [You are\\very kind]
        [How much\\for the lot?]
        [Really not\\serious]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
```

[image][image]

My paintjob isn't great but I hope it portrays the idea I am trying to achieve. The ideal solution should take a tree of any size and label nodes accordingly incase I haven't made this clear.

---

> Edit 1: The labels should go all the way to the nodes. I know about cfr's answer however the levels are specified manually. I don't know how many levels I will have for a tree so I would prefer for this to be done automatically.

Comment: Please provide compilable code! It makes life much easier.

Comment: You want them in the content or really as labels?

Comment: There are other answers which don't require manual specifications, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Please always provide compilable code.*** *It greatly reduces uncertainties, increases the prospect of questions being answered (a) at all and (b) in ways which actually help their askers, is much more efficient, more helpful to new users and generally makes life much easier.*

Guessing how to complete your code, I'm also not clear if you really mean *labels* or if you want to change the nodes' *content*. I'm assuming the latter as labels make little sense here, as far as I can tell. That is, I take the target to be something like this:

[image: results/assumed target]

If so:

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    align=center, 
    base=bottom
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree breadth-first={
      if level=0{temptoksa=1}{
        temptoksa/.option=n,
        for nodewalk={
          while nodewalk valid={u}{u,+temptoksa=.,if level=0{+temptoksa=1}{+temptoksa/.option=n}}
        }{},
      },
      content/.process={ROw2{temptoksa}{content}{#1 #2}}
    }
  }
  [Deadbeef
    [Something
      [Generic\\node]
      [Other\\ generic node]
      [That one\\there]        
    ]
    [Else
      [Client\\Side
        [Become\\data]
        [Bathe in\\data]
      ]
      [Server\\Side
        [One with\\data]
        [Meta\\data
          [Update\\main service]
          [Update\\database]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Kindof
      [You are\\very kind]
      [How much\\for the lot?]
      [Really not\\serious]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

Incidentally, the tree does not look very clear to me, because the edges often end randomly in relation to their children. I would probably go for something more like this:

```
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    align=center, 
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  forked edges,
  align middle children,
```

in the tree's preamble, where `align middle children` is from a custom library and defined as follows:

```
\forestset{
  align middle child/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      if={
        > Ow+P {n children}{isodd(##1)}
      }{
        calign child/.process={
          Ow+n {n children}{(##1+1)/2}
        },
        calign=child edge,
      }{},
    },
  },
  align middle children/.style={
    for tree={align middle child},
  },
}
```

[image: alternative]

But that's a matter of taste, of course.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{
  align middle child/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      if={
        > Ow+P {n children}{isodd(##1)}
      }{
        calign child/.process={
          Ow+n {n children}{(##1+1)/2}
        },
        calign=child edge,
      }{},
    },
  },
  align middle children/.style={
    for tree={align middle child},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    align=center, 
    base=bottom
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree breadth-first={
      if level=0{temptoksa=1}{
        temptoksa/.option=n,
        for nodewalk={
          while nodewalk valid={u}{u,+temptoksa=.,if level=0{+temptoksa=1}{+temptoksa/.option=n}}
        }{},
      },
      content/.process={ROw2{temptoksa}{content}{#1 #2}}
    }
  }
  [Deadbeef
    [Something
      [Generic\\node]
      [Other\\ generic node]
      [That one\\there]        
    ]
    [Else
      [Client\\Side
        [Become\\data]
        [Bathe in\\data]
      ]
      [Server\\Side
        [One with\\data]
        [Meta\\data
          [Update\\main service]
          [Update\\database]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Kindof
      [You are\\very kind]
      [How much\\for the lot?]
      [Really not\\serious]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    align=center, 
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  forked edges,
  align middle children,
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree breadth-first={
      if level=0{temptoksa=1}{
        temptoksa/.option=n,
        for nodewalk={
          while nodewalk valid={u}{u,+temptoksa=.,if level=0{+temptoksa=1}{+temptoksa/.option=n}}
        }{},
      },
      content/.process={ROw2{temptoksa}{content}{#1 #2}}
    }
  }
  [Deadbeef
    [Something
      [Generic\\node]
      [Other\\ generic node]
      [That one\\there]        
    ]
    [Else
      [Client\\Side
        [Become\\data]
        [Bathe in\\data]
      ]
      [Server\\Side
        [One with\\data]
        [Meta\\data
          [Update\\main service]
          [Update\\database]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Kindof
      [You are\\very kind]
      [How much\\for the lot?]
      [Really not\\serious]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't compile your last code. I get `Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgf@temp.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.63 \end{forest}
                  `

Comment: I have no clue what this means. If it helps I am doing this on overleaf.

Comment: @AliCaglayan That's odd. It works fine here. Do you get that error with precisely this code in a new document? Or do you get it when you add the code to an existing document? What version of Forest does Overleaf have?

Comment: @AliCaglayan Overleaf has an old version of Forest (v. 2.0.3), whereas I have what I think is the current version (v. 2.1.5). There were some bugs, so it might be that, and there are some new features, so it could be that.

Comment: I tried it with my original document first, then with a completely new document and it is the same error. Is it possible to make your solution work in this old version then?

Comment: @AliCaglayan I suspect that the use of the argument processor may be the issue, as 2.1 included a significant enhancement of its functionality. I recommend using a newer version of Forest, if you can.

Comment: I am unfortunately restricted to using overleaf as I have no way of producing my own latex builds at the moment. Also, shall I move the discussion to chat to avoid clutter?

Comment: @AliCaglayan In the first tree, replacing the content line with `content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={#1 #2}{temptoksa}{content}` allows compilation on Overleaf. However, this is not enough for the second version with `forked edges`, which apparently depends on more fixes and changes in the new version.

Comment: @AliCaglayan You could try uploading the package to your Overleaf project. That might work. (But certainly not guaranteed.)

Comment: @AliCaglayan If you also comment out the `align middle children` line, the second works with the `content` change, also. Of course, middle children aren't aligned, but you can have the forked edges in that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80861/discussion-between-cfr-and-ali-caglayan).

Comment: On my TeXLive 2018 distribution the code compiles like a charm and precisely reproduces the screen shot.

Comment: @AliCaglayan I've posted working code in chat.

Comment: @marmot Cheers. Pretty sure it's a version issue - Overleaf is behind the curve.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost entirely stolen from [@cfr's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219013/121799), and I will be happy to retract my post if @cfr posts an answer. I'm sure @cfr will also be able to avoid the ugly `\addone`. So this is just in case ....

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\newcommand{\addone}[1]{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{#1+1}\tmp}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
set root label/.style={
    content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={\addone{##1}. ##2}{n()}{content()},
  },
set node label/.style={
    content/.wrap 3 pgfmath args={\addone{##1}.##2 ##3}{n("!r")}{n()}{content()},
  },
set node super label/.style={
    content/.wrap 4 pgfmath args={\addone{##1}.##2.##3  ##4}{n("!rr")}{n("!u")}{n()}{content()},
  },
before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      if level=0{
        set root label,
      }{
        if level=1{
          set node label,
        }{
          if level=2{
            set node super label,
          }{
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
for tree={
    grow'=0,
    align=center, 
    base=bottom
},
[Deadbeef
    [Something
        [Generic\\node]
        [Other\\ generic node]
        [That one\\there]        
    ]
    [Else
        [Client\\Side
            [Become\\data]
            [Bathe in\\data]
        ]
        [Server\\Side
            [One with\\data]
            [Meta\\data
                [Update\\main service]
                [Update\\database]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [Kindof
        [You are\\very kind]
        [How much\\for the lot?]
        [Really not\\serious]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See I was hoping I wouldn't have to specify each level. Is there a way to automatically number them, all the way to the leaves? Specifying labels for each level seems like it could be recursed. I'll edit the original question to make this clearer.

Comment: If you are stuck with version 1 of Forest, this is probably not an unreasonable approach because it is much harder to store results of walks recursively (at least for me), you're stuck with `pgfmath` and the variety of pre-defined multi-step nodewalk steps available is significantly more limited. (You can defined new steps, but fewer are there out-of-the-box.) At least, I guess that's why I might have answered the earlier question that way. (Or maybe I just couldn't figure out something more flexible at the time.)

Comment: But I think current Forest makes it at least rather more straightforward to avoid some of the limitations you and @AliCaglayan mention.

Comment: @cfr I agree and already upvoted your nice answer... ;-)

Comment: I upvoted yours, too, for the record, as I didn't want you to delete it. If anybody has version 1 and can't update, this might well be useful.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, you are very generous. (Honestly, prior to this conversation I didn't even know about the fact that there are two versions.... ;-) But it is good that I did not have to pollute this forum with my unsuccessful attempt to build in a recursion in version 1... ;-)

Comment: @marmot Could you see if you can compile my code? The OP says they get an error, but I can't reproduce it.