# Help with a tree-like design in overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to design a similar tree to this without the allocation choices as I have other treatments. I tried to search maybe for game trees that could help, but nothing was similar enough, maybe except the centipede game, but as I want to write a sentence, it did not come out great :/. I would appreciate it if someone could help

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to make your question look like something else than a *do it for me*. You're not new to this site and were already asked to do so in order to get help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward tree, and there are lots of examples on the site.  When you say "I want to write a sentence" do you intend this to be a tree diagram for linguistics? E.g. [How to draw syntactical trees with parallel leaves for a natural language?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/17600) or [How can I draw simple trees in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/5447) or for non-linguistic trees [Write trees in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/295330) or [How can I produce this tree diagram in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/161231).  I would recommend the [tag:forest] package.

Comment: Maybe see also [tikz pgf - Horizontal - Vertical connectors in a tree (in place of slanted lines) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218411/horizontal-vertical-connectors-in-a-tree-in-place-of-slanted-lines). For a hint, I usually search for some terms then use "image search" then quickly look for related images